# Build AlerDialog outside of an Activity (RecyclerView.Viewholder)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog, android-alertdialog

I'm using a RecyclerView and want to open an AlertDialog whenever an item in the RecyclerView is long-clicked.

In the RecyclerView's ViewHolder, i have implemented the clicklistener

```
 @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        //Open Alert dialog to delete item

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        ...

}
```

As i can read here: http://goo.gl/Kd1c7i one needs to pass "MyActivity.this" to the AlertDialog.Builder constructor but since the ViewHolder is a static part of the RecyclerView Adapter, i cannot refer to "MyActivity.this".
Hence i still get the error:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

So how can i create an AlertDialog from class which does not extend Activity?

@Edit: More code for more information:

Here is my RecyclerView Adapter constructor:

```
RecyclerViewCourseAdapter(ArrayList<Course> courses, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    if (courses == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("courses ArrayList must not be null");
    }

    mCourseArrayList = courses;
}
```

I store the given context as private in the Adapter class:

```
private Context context;
```

This is my ViewHolder:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,View.OnLongClickListener {

    //Initialize views in Viewholder
    TextView mTextViewFirst;
    TextView mTextViewSecond;
    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mEndPercentageTextView;

    //Context to refer to app context (for intent, dialog etc)
    Context context;

    //Adapter to notifiy data set changed
    RecyclerViewCourseAdapter mCourseAdapter;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView, Context context, RecyclerViewCourseAdapter mCourseAdapter) {

        super(itemView);
        this.context = context;
        this.mCourseAdapter = mCourseAdapter;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        mTextViewFirst = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_firstLine);
        mTextViewSecond = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_secondLine);
        mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        mEndPercentageTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.end_percentage_textview);
    }
```

This is how i create the Viewholders:

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Inflate layout
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_course, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(itemView, context, this);

    return vh;
}
```

So i create my ViewHolder with the context stored in the Adapter.

If something is still unlcear, here is my whole class: 
https://github.com/Tak3r07/UniHelper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tak3r07/CourseStatistics/RecyclerViewCourseAdapter.java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every `View` has a context, change:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
```

See the documentation for more info:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()

Answer (score 1):

Alter your ViewHolder class to store a Context like this:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener {

    private Context mContext;

    public ViewHolder(View v, Context mContext) {
        super(v);
        this.mContext = mContext;

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        //Open Alert dialog to delete item

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.mContext);

        ...
    }
}
```

To pass your Context to the ViewHolder you must first pass it to the RecyclerView Adapter.

If you create your Adapter inside a fragment (as I mostly do) you should get the Context by overriding the onAttach-Method

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.mContext = activity; // Activity is a subclass of Context
}
```

Otherwise you get the Context by calling MyActivity.this

Comment: I already did this but it throws me the error described above

Comment: That exception is thrown because the context is null when you create the dialog. Please post more of your code and I am sure we can figure this out. There seems to be something wrong with how you pass the context to the ViewHolder.

Comment: I have added some information and the github link to the class if something is still unclear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the exception thrown when the RecyclerView loads or when you perform the onClick action?

When you are using CourseStatistics.getAppContext() to create your intent, use the stored context instead. You have to cast it to your activity though: (ActivityClassName) mContext

Comment: It was thrown when i had performed a click. Sorry, i did not have update the github repo, i didnt use the class CourseStatistics anymore.
@deive 's answer did the trick: using view.getContet() in AlertBuilder constructor!

Comment: Perfect. Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can some how find a context to your Builder, one alternative is to pass it as an argument.